# Opening Ubuntu from the hard drive

Tags: boot

I have an HP box with a 32bit processor and 80gb hard drive that currently has XP pro as the OS. I downloaded Ubuntu to the hard drive  but can't get it to open or boot. I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a bootable pendrive using any available software (I prefer  [LiLi for windows](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)).
2. Reboot and press <kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> to go to
   Boot Menu.
3. Change Boot Priority (Set USB/Flashdrive first using arrow keys).
4. Exit and save changes. Reboot.
5. Now you will be presented with ubuntu logo and installation proceeds (Try ubuntu/Install Ubuntu).
6. If you have created partitions previously, then you can install ubuntu in any one of them.
7. Else, you need to create separate partition for ubuntu. Use GParted for doing that.
8. How to use GParted ?, Install it while ubuntu is running on your USB from apt-get install command (You should choose 'Try Ubuntu option for this').

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to test ubuntu without installing, you can use VirtualBox, a free program provided and maintained by Oracle.  This way you can create a virtual machine on your windows box and install it there.  You would mount the ISO you downloaded as a CD image in the VM's configuration.

If you wanted to install ubuntu you will need to burn the ISO to a thumb drive or dvd.  If you are using DVDs I recommend imgburn and for usb drives I like to use Rufus.  These are personal preference though.